# Как прописать условие в Python если после точки в десятичной дроби стоит 0, то писать целое число

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Это то что я пытался написать 

    forfourth1 = 7
    forfourth2 = 1.4
    
    kPAfour = ((forfourth1 * 1000) / int((forfourth2 * 1000)))
    
    if kPAfour == float(kPAfour):
        print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", round(kPAfour, 2))
    elif kPAfour = int(kPAfour):
        print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", int(kPAfour))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
forfourth1 = 7
forfourth2 = 1.4
    
kPAfour = ((forfourth1 * 1000) / int((forfourth2 * 1000)))
    
if type(kPAfour) == float:
    print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", round(kPAfour, 2))
elif type(kPAfour) = int:
    print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", int(kPAfour))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 3.0
if num % 1 == 0:
    num = int(num)
```

`%` - это деление с остатком, т.е., если мы делим число на 1, и остаток равен 0, то сработает оператор if и преобразует float в int.

Answer (score 0):

```
forfourth1 = 7
forfourth2 = 1.4

kPAfour = ((forfourth1 * 1000) / int((forfourth2 * 1000)))

if (kPAfour * 10) % 10 != 0:
    print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", round(kPAfour, 2))
else:
    print("Там сказано в м в квадрате поэтому, впиши в ответ:", int(kPAfour))
```

В данном случае не нужно проверять тип переменной, т.к. операция не целочисленного деления в любом случае вернет результат типа float.
Если условия всего 2, не стоит использовать конструкцию if elif, т.к она будет неполной и выдаст ошибку, нужно использовать if else.
Ну и вот эта запись прямо ввела меня в ступор kPAfour = int(kPAfour)

Comment: у `float` есть метод `is_integer`

Comment: Is_integer проверит является ли число с точкой целым, а по условию, как я понимаю, нужно проверить является ли первым знаком после точки 0. После 0 ведь могут быть ещё сотые, чысячные и т.д. Думаю, что is_integer в данном случае бесполезен, либо условие сформировано неправильно.